# One series name in higcharts not getting populated even though json send the correct information

Tags: json, highcharts

The last series in a bar chart is showing "Series 4" as a name, even though its proper name is coming correcty from json file.

The information from the json file comes from a SQL query that prints the information in a string with the following format:

```
[
{"name": "Operation","data": [{"y":3000, "second": 1500, "third": 5}]},
{"name": "Mechanical","data": [{"y":2515, "second": 515, "third": 8}]},
{"name": "Electrical","data": [{"y":1800, "second": 475, "third": 10}]},
{"name": "Operation Slag","data": [{"y":1000, "second": 1500, "third": 7}]}
]
```

Since the colors of the series are set manually, I am using the below to add just data and name to each series:

```
jspData.forEach(function(jspData, i) {
    Delays.series[i].setData(jspData.data);
    Delays.series[i].setName(jspData.name);
}];
```

This is working as expected until the last series which show "Series 4" name and not "Operation Slag".

```
$(function () {
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $.getJSON('getData.json', function(jspData) {
            var Delays = new Highcharts.chart({
                chart: {
                    renderTo: 'Delays',
                    type: 'bar'
                },
                xAxis: {
                    categories: [''],
                    lineWidth: 0,
                    minorTickLength: 0,
                    tickLength: 0,
                    gridLineWidth: 0,
                    minorGridLineWidth: 0,
                    title: {
                        text: null
                    }
                },
                yAxis: {
                    gridLineWidth: 0,
                    minorGridLineWidth: 0, 
                    lineWidth: 0,
                    tickWidth: 0,
                    tickLength: 0,
                    min: 0,
                    title: null,
                    labels: {
                        enabled: false,
                    }
                },
                tooltip: {
                    enabled:true,
                    style:{fontSize:'10px', fontFamily:"sans-serif"},
                    formatter: function() {
                            console.log(this);
                            return 'Total duration: ' + this.y + 'min<br/>Delay Code: ' + this.point.second + '<br/>Count of Events: ' + this.point.third;
                    },
                },
                    plotOptions: {
                        bar: {
                            borderWidth: 0.5,
                            dataLabels: {
                                    enabled: true,
                                    format: '{series.name}',
                                    style: {
                                        fontSize: "10px",
                                        fontWeight:'normal',
                                        textOutline: false,
                                        fontFamily: 'sans-serif',
                                    },
                                }
                            },
                        series: {
                            groupPadding: 0,
                            pointPadding: 0,
                        },
                    },
                    legend:{
                        enabled:false,
                    },
                    series: [{
                       color:'#4572A7',
                       data: []
                    }, {
                      color:'#89A54E',
                      data: []

                   }, {
                     color:'#AA4643', 
                     data: []
                   }, {
                    color:'#A1745B',
                    data: []
                   }],


            });

                    jspData.forEach(function(jspData, i) {
                        Delays.series[i].setData(jspData.data);
                        Delays.series[i].setName(jspData.name);


                    }); 

        });
    });
});
```

Last series name should not be "Series 4" but "Operation Slag". Chart is render porperly all other data is populated correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `setName` method is internal and it requires to redraw the chart. In your case it's enough to change the order of calls, because `setData` causes `redraw`:

```
jspData.forEach(function(jspData, i) {
    Delays.series[i].setName(jspData.name);
    Delays.series[i].setData(jspData.data);
});
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/0qkf26zp/

API: https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Series#setData